# Loading Google Maps and fetching markers with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to fetch and populate ajax response lat and log and mark it on google map. The issue is, string markers 'str' variable which is inside ajax success event can't bind to 'markers' variable directly like 'markers = str'. However, when I put a breakpoints on 'str' variable and copied the output and manually used 'markers = copied data', this works. The code shown below works, but when I un-comment one of 'markers = str' it does not work. I'm not sure if I need some kind of delayer. Please help.

```
<script>

    //general variables declarations
    var markers;
    var map;

    $("#showdata").click(function () {
        $.when(LoadReports()).done(function () {
            initialize();
        });
    });

    function LoadReports() {

        var Params = {
            startdate: "2015-02-20",
            enddate: "2015-06-22",
            ticketstate: "1",
            city: "Bokaro"
        };

        var arr = [];
        var str;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Map/GeoReports/GeographycalReports?startdate=' + Params.startdate + '&enddate=' + Params.enddate + '&ticketstate=' + Params.ticketstate + '&city=' + Params.city,
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, dt) {
                    var msg = '<h6><a href=' + 'http://www.website.com/report.aspx?id=' + dt.PostID + '>' + dt.PostTitle + '</a></h6>Created On: ' + dt.DateCreated + '<br/>Current State: ' + dt.PostState;
                    arr.push("[" + dt.Latitude + ", " + dt.Longitude + ", '" + htmlEncode(msg) + "'" + "]");
                });
                str = '[' + arr.join(',') + ']';
                //markers = str;
            }
        });

        //markers = str;
        markers = [[23.6474369, 86.1573708999999, '<h6><a href=http://www.website.com/report.aspx?id=d87a9eb1-9949-48bd-83cb-c2b1e5f18cbf>this is video post..</a></h6>Created On: 20-Feb-2015, 09:58 AM<br/>Current State: Reported'], [23.7978583, 85.8844404, '<h6><a href=http://www.website.com/report.aspx?id=af10a244-c97d-4b50-8f88-ff7993fb1a93>20/02/2015 event test report heading</a></h6>Created On: 20-Feb-2015, 09:58 AM<br/>Current State: Reported'], [22.790854, 86.1542407, '<h6><a href=http://www.website.com/report.aspx?id=02da0719-5d72-4d7e-8f16-4eb1377b1cf1>22/04/2015 event test report heading</a></h6>Created On: 21-Feb-2015, 09:19 AM<br/>Current State: Reported'], [22.783474, 86.157689, '<h6><a href=http://www.website.com/report.aspx?id=aa946656-52df-4ab6-bbe9-36008cd3156d>21/02/2015 event test report heading</a></h6>Created On: 21-Feb-2015, 01:22 PM<br/>Current State: Reported']];
    }

    function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(23.6474369, 86.1573708999999);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 9,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            mapTypeControlOptions: { style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU },
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        addMarker();
    }

    function addMarker() {
        var global_markers = [];

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var lat = parseFloat(markers[i][0]);
            var lng = parseFloat(markers[i][1]);
            var trailhead_name = markers[i][2];

            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

            var contentString = "<html><body><div><p><h2>" + trailhead_name + "</h2></p></div></body></html>";

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: "Coordinates: " + lat + " , " + lng + " | Trailhead name: " + trailhead_name
            });

            marker['infowindow'] = contentString;

            global_markers[i] = marker;

            google.maps.event.addListener(global_markers[i], 'click', function () {
                infowindow.setContent(this['infowindow']);
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            });
        }
    }

    function htmlEncode(value) {
        return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
    }
</script>
```

Html page:

```
<input id="showdata" type="button" name="showdata" value="Show on Map" style="margin: inherit;">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 550px; height: 450px"></div>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, i resolved the issue using more better way. Here is the script code, html code is still same.

```
    $("#showdata").click(function () {
        initialize();
    });

    var geocoder;
    var map;
    var places;
    var markers = [];

    function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latlngCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(23.6474369, 86.1573708999999);
        var mapOptions = {
            center: latlngCenter,
            zoom: 7,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
        fetchPlaces();
    }

    var fetchPlaces = function () {

        var Params = {
            startdate: "2015-02-20",
            enddate: "2015-06-22",
            ticketstate: "1",
            city: "Bokaro"
        };

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: ''
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Map/GeoReports/GeographycalReports?startdate=' + Params.startdate + '&enddate=' + Params.enddate + '&ticketstate=' + Params.ticketstate + '&city=' + Params.city,
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, dt) {
                    var msg = '<h6><a href=' + 'http://www.website.com/report.aspx?id=' + dt.PostID + '>' + dt.PostTitle + '</a></h6>Created On: ' + dt.DateCreated + '<br/>Current State: ' + dt.PostState;
                    tmpLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(dt.Latitude, dt.Longitude);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: tmpLatLng,
                        title: "Coordinates: " + dt.Latitude + " , " + dt.Longitude
                    });
                    bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, msg);
                });
            }
        });
    }

    var bindInfoWindow = function (marker, map, infowindow, html) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infowindow.setContent(html);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }
```